# The gradient of an output w.r.t network weights that holds another output constant

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, gradient-descent

Let's assume I have a simple MLP

[image]

And I have a gradient of some loss function with respect to the output layer to get G = [0, -1] (that is, increasing the second output variable decreases the loss function).

If I take the gradient of G with respect to my network parameters and apply a gradient decent weight update the second output variable should increase, but nothing is said about the first output variable, and a scaled application of the gradient will almost certainly change the output variable (be it increasing it or decreasing it)

How can I modify my loss function, or any of the gradient calculations, to ensure that the first output does not change?

Answer (score 1):

Update: I misunderstood the question. This is the new answer.

For this purpose, you need to update connections between the hidden layer and the second output unit only, while keep those between the hidden layer and the first output unit intact.

**The first approach is to introduce two sets of variables**: one for connections between the hidden layer and the first output unit, one for the rest. Then you can combine them using `tf.stack`, and pass a `var_list` to get the corresponding derivatives. It's like (Just for illustration. Not tested. Use with care):

```py
out1 = tf.matmul(hidden, W_h_to_out1) + b_h_to_out1
out2 = tf.matmul(hidden, W_h_to_out2) + b_h_to_out2
out = tf.stack([out1, out2])
out = tf.transpose(tf.reshape(out, [2, -1]))
loss = some_function_of(out)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)
train_op_second_unit = optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=[W_h_to_out2, b_h_to_out2])
```

**Another approach is to use a mask.** This is easier to implement and more flexible when you work with some frameworks (say, slim, Keras, etc.), and I'll recommend this way. The idea to hide the first output unit to the loss function, while do not change the second output unit. **This can be done using a binary variable: multiply something by 1 if you want to keep it, and multiply it by 0 to drop it.** Here's the code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# let's make our tiny dataset: (x, y) pairs, where x = (x1, x2, x3), y = (y1, y2),
# and y1 = x1+x2+x3, y2 = x1^2+x2^2+x3^2

# n_sample data points
n_sample = 8
data_x = np.random.random((n_sample, 3))
data_y = np.zeros((n_sample, 2))
data_y[:, 0] += np.sum(data_x, axis=1)
data_y[:, 1] += np.sum(data_x**2, axis=1)
data_y += 0.01 * np.random.random((n_sample, 2))  # add some noise


# build graph
# suppose we have a network of shape [3, 4, 2], i.e.: one hidden layer of size 4.

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3], name='x')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2], name='y')
mask = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2], name='mask')

W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[3, 4], stddev=0.1), name='W1')
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[4], stddev=0.1), name='b1')
hidden = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1)
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[4, 2], stddev=0.1), name='W2')
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[2], stddev=0.1), name='b2')
out = tf.matmul(hidden, W2) + b2
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(out - y))

# multiply out by mask, thus out[0] is "invisible" to loss, and its gradient will not be propagated
masked_out = mask * out
loss2 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(masked_out - y))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)
train_op_all = optimizer.minimize(loss)  # update all variables in the network
train_op12 = optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=[W2, b2])  # update hidden -> output layer
train_op2 = optimizer.minimize(loss2, var_list=[W2, b2])  # update hidden -> second output unit


sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
mask_out1 = np.zeros((n_sample, 2))
mask_out1[:, 1] += 1.0
# print(mask_out1)
print(sess.run([hidden, out, loss, loss2], feed_dict={x: data_x, y: data_y, mask: mask_out1}))

# In this case, only out2 is updated. You see the loss and loss2 decreases.
sess.run(train_op2, feed_dict={x: data_x, y:data_y, mask: mask_out1})
print(sess.run([hidden, out, loss, loss2], feed_dict={x: data_x, y:data_y, mask: mask_out1}))

# In this case, both out1 and out2 is updated. You see the loss and loss2 decreases.
sess.run(train_op12, feed_dict={x: data_x, y:data_y, mask: mask_out1})
print(sess.run([hidden, out, loss, loss2], feed_dict={x: data_x, y:data_y, mask: mask_out1}))

# In this case, everything is updated. You see the loss and loss2 decreases.
sess.run(train_op_all, feed_dict={x: data_x, y:data_y, mask: mask_out1})
print(sess.run([hidden, out, loss, loss2], feed_dict={x: data_x, y:data_y, mask: mask_out1}))
sess.close()
```

=======================Below is the old answer==============================

To get derivatives w.r.t. different variables, you can pass a `var_list` to decide which variable to update. Here is an example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# let's make our tiny dataset: (x, y) pairs, where x = (x1, x2, x3), y = (y1, y2),
# and y1 = x1+x2+x3, y2 = x1^2+x2^2+x3^2

# n_sample data points
n_sample = 8
data_x = np.random.random((n_sample, 3))
data_y = np.zeros((n_sample, 2))
data_y[:, 0] += np.sum(data_x, axis=1)
data_y[:, 1] += np.sum(data_x**2, axis=1)
data_y += 0.01 * np.random.random((n_sample, 2))  # add some noise


# build graph
# suppose we have a network of shape [3, 4, 2], i.e.: one hidden layer of size 4.

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3], name='x')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2], name='y')

W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[3, 4], stddev=0.1), name='W1')
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[4], stddev=0.1), name='b1')
hidden = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1)
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[4, 2], stddev=0.1), name='W2')
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape=[2], stddev=0.1), name='b2')
out = tf.matmul(hidden, W2) + b2

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(out - y))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1)
# You can pass a variable list to decide which variable(s) to minimize.
train_op_second_layer = optimizer.minimize(loss, var_list=[W2, b2])
# If there is no var_list, all variables will be updated.
train_op_all = optimizer.minimize(loss)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print(sess.run([W1, b1, W2, b2, loss], feed_dict={x: data_x, y:data_y}))

# In this case, only W2 and b2 are updated. You see the loss decreases.
sess.run(train_op_second_layer, feed_dict={x: data_x, y:data_y})
print(sess.run([W1, b1, W2, b2, loss], feed_dict={x: data_x, y:data_y}))

# In this case, all variables are updated. You see the loss decreases.
sess.run(train_op_all, feed_dict={x: data_x, y:data_y})
print(sess.run([W1, b1, W2, b2, loss], feed_dict={x: data_x, y:data_y}))
sess.close()
```

Comment: How about setting `trainable=False`, [Variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/state_ops/variables)

Comment: this is not the same thing -- the issue is that both outputs are affected by a change in weights - applying the gradient of output with respect to weights induces a change in both outputs, but we want the gradient to somehow account for the fact that one output should remain constant after the gradient step

Comment: @Robert Oh, I see. I misunderstood your question. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Robert Does my new answer help? You need to know that output is not a variable itself: it's just a combination of other variables. If you want to control output, you need to control variables that affects output.

Comment: @xxi Yes, you can. But I'm afraid that if you set a variable to be not trainable, you are not able to train it again. Sometimes one may want to train a variable for some steps, then freeze it, then train again. (Say, in the training procedure of GAN) For this case, it's better to use a `var_list`.

Comment: @soloice unfortunately this isn't right either.. the issue isn't likely to be a code-based one, but rather a mathy one. According to your new answer, the only weights that could be updated are the 4 weights connecting the hidden layer to the "changable" output node which would severely limit the capacity of the network.

Comment: But this is the only way. If you change other parts of the network, another output will also change. This is simply math.